# Makeindex: Greek and Latin letters sorting

Tags: makeindex

I am using `makeindex` to generate a list of symbols. But by default, it sorts Greek letters before Latin ones, I'd like it to be the other way around. Is there any way to do it, possibly with some `.ist` index style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The answer to your question is different depending on how you currently make your index and how you currently write Greek letters. There are several possibilities, each with a somewhat different approach for a solution. So if you can provide a small example document that can be compiled and that has four symbols in it (two Latin and two Greek) then it will be possible to answer the question without having to guess what your setup is.